# Solve the quadratic congrunce

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the following quadratic congreunce

$x^2+ 7x + 10 \equiv 0$ (mod $11$).

I want to know a general and easy method how to solve this kind of questions.

Comment: You can divide by two modulo $11$, so you can complete the square. The same idea should be helpful for solving quadratics $x^2 + bx + c \equiv 0 \mod{p}$ when $p$ is an odd prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0$ (mod $p$), if $p$ is an odd prime not dividing $a$, then this is the same as solving a simpler question about quadratic residues $y^2\equiv b^2-4ac$ (mod $p$), and $y\equiv 2ax+b$ (mod $p$).

Answer (score -2):

Use the quadratic formula $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

so $b^2-4ac = 7^2 - 40 = 9 = 3^2$

so $\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} = \pm 3$

and $-b \pm 3 = -10,-4$

and so the answers are -5 and -2.

Comment: The quadratic formula will only find you two particular solutions if the equation has two integer roots. What about $x^2+3x+4$? This has two complex roots, but when considered as an equation modulo $11$, it has solution $x\equiv 3,5$ (mod $11$). Also, the roots of $x^2+7x+10$ are $-2$ and $-5$.

Comment: no it works in that case too, you (obviously) compute the square roots mod 11

Comment: Perhaps you should allude to that by adding the word "mod" somewhere in your answer? I didn't think it was obvious that you should compute the square roots modulo $11$, especially since you only gave two explicit integers as your answer, and I have never seen the notation $y\equiv \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ (mod $p$) used: $y^2\equiv b^2-4ac$ (mod $p$) I think is considerably more commonplace, and makes a lot more sense.

Comment: hint: we're trying to solve equation mod 11